# How to get the full uriPattern for a NavDeepLink in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have an app that uses federated urls that should open in the app. It does this using deepLinks.

The issue, is that I need to provide the full URIpattern to the composable, in order to figure out where to fetch data from. How would I provide the full URL to the composable?

Example:

```
composable(
  route = "c/{name}/{instance}",
  deepLinks = DEFAULT_LEMMY_INSTANCES.map { instance ->
    navDeepLink { uriPattern = "$instance/c/{name}" }
  },
  arguments = listOf(
    navArgument("name") {
      type = NavType.StringType
    }
  )
) {
  LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
  val name = it.arguments?.getString("name")!!
  // TODO figure out how to get instance / full URI pattern?
```

Answer (score 5):

This is precisely what the [`KEY_DEEP_LINK_INTENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#KEY_DEEP_LINK_INTENT()) extra is for: this is the full `Intent` used to trigger your deep link - it is the `data` field in that `Intent` that contains the full `Uri`:

```
val deepLinkIntent: Intent = it.arguments?.getParcelable(
    NavController.KEY_DEEP_LINK_INTENT)
val fullUri = deepLinkIntent?.data
```

Comment: thanks, almost gave up. this seems like the way to go when you have multiple query parameters and order is not guaranteed. otherwise uri pattern matching will fail.